# proportions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I am trying to calculate a proportion of a portion to a total. My table looks like this:

| State | City | Money_Awarded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | NYC | 5 |
| NY | QBC | 7 |
| NJ | NJC | 8 |
| NJ | ABC | 6 |

I have written a query that gives me totals per state (using SUM and GROUP BY state), but I am having trouble returning another column that would calculate the proportion of EACH state to the total. I could write a sum query for the Money_Awarded column and then use the result, but I'd like to do this programmatically. How can I do this? I am using MySQL

Comment: Version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select state, sum(money_awarded),
       sum(money_awarded) * 1.0 / sum(sum(money_awarded)) over () as ratio
from t
group by state;
```

EDIT:

Older versions of MySQL do not support window functions, so you can instead do:

```
select t.state, sum(t.money_awarded),
       sum(t.money_awarded) * 1.0 / tt.total_money_awarded as ratio
from t cross join
     (select sum(money_awarded) as total_money_awarded
      from t
     ) tt
group by t.state, tt.total_money_awarded
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. I got an error. Are there any other techniques? It told me that "Queries can not contain both windowed and non-windowed aggregation"